# How many troops died on D-day?

Tags: world-war-two, 20th-century, dday, ww2-european-theater

How many troops (allied and axis) died at Normandy beach on June 6th, 1944? I've searched all over the internet, but can't find an accurate number.

Comment: I have a research paper to write and this site was a lifesaver

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've pulled some information off the citations from wikipedia,

[D-Day Museum](http://www.ddaymuseum.co.uk/faq.htm)

**How many Allied and German casualties were there on D-Day, and in the Battle of Normandy?**

> “Casualties” refers to all losses suffered by the armed forces:
>   killed, wounded, missing in action (meaning that their bodies were not
>   found) and prisoners of war. There is no "official" casualty figure
>   for D-Day. Under the circumstances, accurate record keeping was very
>   difficult. For example, some troops who were listed as missing may
>   actually have landed in the wrong place, and have rejoined their
>   parent unit only later.
>
> In April and May 1944, the Allied air forces lost nearly 12,000 men
>   and over 2,000 aircraft in operations which paved the way for D-Day.
>
> The Allied casualties figures for D-Day have generally been estimated
>   at 10,000, including 2500 dead. Broken down by nationality, the usual
>   D-Day casualty figures are approximately 2700 British, 946 Canadians,
>   and 6603 Americans. However recent painstaking research by the US
>   National D-Day Memorial Foundation has achieved a more accurate - and
>   much higher - figure for the Allied personnel who were killed on
>   D-Day. They have recorded the names of individual Allied personnel
>   killed on 6 June 1944 in Operation Overlord, and so far they have
>   verified 2499 American D-Day fatalities and 1915 from the other Allied
>   nations, a total of 4414 dead (much higher than the traditional figure
>   of 2500 dead). Further research may mean that these numbers will
>   increase slightly in future. The details of this research will in due
>   course be available on the Foundation's website at www.dday.org. This
>   new research means that the casualty figures given for individual
>   units in the next few paragraphs are no doubt inaccurate, and
>   hopefully more accurate figures will one day be calculated.
>
> Casualties on the British beaches were roughly 1000 on Gold Beach and
>   the same number on Sword Beach. The remainder of the British losses
>   were amongst the airborne troops: some 600 were killed or wounded, and
>   600 more were missing; 100 glider pilots also became casualties. The
>   losses of 3rd Canadian Division at Juno Beach have been given as 340
>   killed, 574 wounded and 47 taken prisoner.
>
> The breakdown of US casualties was 1465 dead, 3184 wounded, 1928
>   missing and 26 captured. Of the total US figure, 2499 casualties were
>   from the US airborne troops (238 of them being deaths). The casualties
>   at Utah Beach were relatively light: 197, including 60 missing.
>   However, the US 1st and 29th Divisions together suffered around 2000
>   casualties at Omaha Beach.
>
> The total German casualties on D-Day are not known, but are estimated
>   as being between 4000 and 9000 men.
>
> Naval losses for June 1944 included 24 warships and 35 merchantmen or
>   auxiliaries sunk, and a further 120 vessels damaged.
>
> Over 425,000 Allied and German troops were killed, wounded or went
>   missing during the Battle of Normandy. This figure includes over
>   209,000 Allied casualties, with nearly 37,000 dead amongst the ground
>   forces and a further 16,714 deaths amongst the Allied air forces. Of
>   the Allied casualties, 83,045 were from 21st Army Group (British,
>   Canadian and Polish ground forces), 125,847 from the US ground forces.
>   The losses of the German forces during the Battle of Normandy can only
>   be estimated. Roughly 200,000 German troops were killed or wounded.
>   The Allies also captured 200,000 prisoners of war (not included in the
>   425,000 total, above). During the fighting around the Falaise Pocket
>   (August 1944) alone, the Germans suffered losses of around 90,000,
>   including prisoners.
>
> Today, twenty-seven war cemeteries hold the remains of over 110,000
>   dead from both sides: 77,866 German, 9386 American, 17,769 British,
>   5002 Canadian and 650 Poles.
>
> Between 15,000 and 20,000 French civilians were killed, mainly as a
>   result of Allied bombing. Thousands more fled their homes to escape
>   the fighting.

Comment: This is the same as my answer.

Comment: @ChristopherRayl: When you both simply pull the answer from another website, you can hardly lay claim to exclusivity. If this is what this site is going to become, it's never going to get out of private beta.

Comment: The numbers seem a bit *too* specific; I doubt that they could have  kept such immaculate records. Though they do acknowledge that the records probably weren't spot on, I wouldn't feel comfortable past the hundreds place of these figures (for personnel losses, not materiel losses).

Comment: Interestingly, roughly the same number of people were injured or killed in the first eleven hours of the last day of World War I than on all of D-Day: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/November_11,_1918#Last_casualties (10,000 casualties, 2,700 deaths).

Comment: The Allies lost 2000 aircraft in April-May? 200 vessels sunk or damaged? How is this possible when the Allies have air and Naval superiority? Already this wiki article claims that the 24 warships sunk figure is wrong: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normandy_landings#Naval_losses

Comment: @SchwitJanwityanujit lost to ground fire, mines, accidents, you name it. Not every ship is lost to another ship, not every aircraft to another aircraft. The US lost several dozen aircraft during Desert Storm, despite the Iraqi air force never getting off the ground...

Comment: I can't say with any degree of certainty, but the number of lost aircraft might also include the gliders used by Airborne troops - a good deal of them were damaged beyond viable repair. I don't know if the allied aircraft numbers included the gliders though.

Comment: vessels would include landing craft and other small ships.

Answer (score 17):

Short Answer:

Allies: 10,000
Germans: 4,000 - 9,000

Specifics:

> “Casualties” refers to all losses suffered by the armed forces:
>   killed, wounded, missing in action (meaning that their bodies were not
>   found) and prisoners of war. There is no "official" casualty figure
>   for D-Day. Under the circumstances, accurate record keeping was very
>   difficult. For example, some troops who were listed as missing may
>   actually have landed in the wrong place, and have rejoined their
>   parent unit only later.
>
> In April and May 1944, the Allied air forces lost nearly 12,000 men
>   and over 2,000 aircraft in operations which paved the way for D-Day.
>
> The Allied casualties figures for D-Day have generally been estimated
>   at 10,000, including 2500 dead. Broken down by nationality, the usual
>   D-Day casualty figures are approximately 2700 British, 946 Canadians,
>   and 6603 Americans. However recent painstaking research by the US
>   National D-Day Memorial Foundation has achieved a more accurate - and
>   much higher - figure for the Allied personnel who were killed on
>   D-Day. They have recorded the names of individual Allied personnel
>   killed on 6 June 1944 in Operation Overlord, and so far they have
>   verified 2499 American D-Day fatalities and 1915 from the other Allied
>   nations, a total of 4414 dead (much higher than the traditional figure
>   of 2500 dead). Further research may mean that these numbers will
>   increase slightly in future. The details of this research will in due
>   course be available on the Foundation's website at www.dday.org. This
>   new research means that the casualty figures given for individual
>   units in the next few paragraphs are no doubt inaccurate, and
>   hopefully more accurate figures will one day be calculated.
>
> Casualties on the British beaches were roughly 1000 on Gold Beach and
>   the same number on Sword Beach. The remainder of the British losses
>   were amongst the airborne troops: some 600 were killed or wounded, and
>   600 more were missing; 100 glider pilots also became casualties. The
>   losses of 3rd Canadian Division at Juno Beach have been given as 340
>   killed, 574 wounded and 47 taken prisoner.
>
> The breakdown of US casualties was 1465 dead, 3184 wounded, 1928
>   missing and 26 captured. Of the total US figure, 2499 casualties were
>   from the US airborne troops (238 of them being deaths). The casualties
>   at Utah Beach were relatively light: 197, including 60 missing.
>   However, the US 1st and 29th Divisions together suffered around 2000
>   casualties at Omaha Beach.
>
> The total German casualties on D-Day are not known, but are estimated
>   as being between 4000 and 9000 men.
>
> Naval losses for June 1944 included 24 warships and 35 merchantmen or
>   auxiliaries sunk, and a further 120 vessels damaged.

[Source: D-Day Museum](http://www.ddaymuseum.co.uk/faq.htm#casualities)

Comment: http://theddaystory.com/faq.htm#casualities 404